# Change selection style of object in fabric.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fabricjs

I am using fabric plugin  in my project.when object is selected we get selected area with with the following design. Can I attached images to  selected area with some pic as shown below:-

I set text using ,

```
hw[i] = new fabric.Text($(this).val(), {
                left : 100,
                top : 100,
                fontSize : 20
            });
```

Currently , I am getting :

[image]

and i wish to get ,

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: you can only customise the corner color, corner size , transparent border and stuffs like that for the selection, Im not sure if this is possible..

Comment: @PrasannaAarthi i am trying  textShadow: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 5px 5px 5px' , but what if i only wish to change blur sixe i.e last value??

Comment: try rgba(0,0,0.3) 0 0 5px ..

Comment: @PrasannaAarthi  no i want something like obj.set('top', h); this set only top value i want to just set blur size , and on another button want to set shadow color . hope you get my question

Comment: you want to set blur on text using textshadow or you want to blur an object say an image?

Comment: @PrasannaAarthi  set blur on text using textshadow>

Comment: @anam if you find any solution then please share it

Answer (score 3):

While you cannot do that directly with Fabric JS, someone made an extension for it:

GitHub site: https://github.com/pixolith/fabricjs-customise-controls-extension

Live demo: http://pixolith.github.io/fabricjs-customise-controls-extension/example/index.html)

This will allow you to assign change the handle images and their actions.

After adding the extension you can add something like this: to get the actions

```
fabric.Canvas.prototype.customiseControls({
    tl: {
        action: 'remove',
    },
    tr: {
        action: 'rotate'
    },
    br: {
        action: 'scaleY',
    },
});
```

Then change the icons with:

```
fabric.Object.prototype.customiseCornerIcons({
    settings: {
        borderColor: 'black',
        cornerSize: 25,
        cornerShape: 'circle',
        cornerBackgroundColor: 'black',
        cornerPadding: 10
    },
    tl: {
        icon: 'icon/trashcan.svg'
    },
    tr: {
        icon: 'icon/rotate.svg'
    },
    br: {
        icon: 'icon/scale.svg'
    },
});
```